# Force serialization of property that has [JsonIgnore] attribute

Tags: c#, json.net

Is it possible to somehow force serialization of `x` property?

```
public class Cake
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    // possibly some attribute like [ReadOnlyJsonIgnore] or [JsonIgnoreReadOnly] would be nice
    public int x { get; set; }
}
```

But keep `[JsonIgnore]` for deserialization only? What I want to achieve is some form of read only properties. So they can be serialized but can't be deserialized, are simply ignored like they aren't there.

Comment: What is the purpose of letting JsonIgnore if you want to serialize it :) ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound To ignore deserialization only.

Comment: So just use different classes : one for serialization and aonther for deserialization. The latter should not contain the x property;

Comment: @CodeNotFound yeah that's the easiest solution but I wanted to try to avoid that

Comment: Always make your code clear. Use searate classes for different purposes makes your code maintenable. Just using one class doesn't mean it is the good solution.

Comment: @CodeNotFound But if I have 20 classes I have 2x more for serialization and deserialization, that means 60 classes 60 files for each class, 40 additional DTO classes that's 40 more files

Comment: If you want readonly property, why not use readonly property? `public int x { get;}`

Comment: @LoneWolfMcQuade  check if you can either`JsonConverter` or `ContractResolver` to override the default deserialization behavior.

Comment: You could also “ignore” deserialization by resetting all “ignored” values after deserializing them.

Comment: @poke and where would I do that?

Comment: `var cake = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cake>(rawData); cake.X = default; cake.Y = default; …`

Comment: If you make the serializable classes inherit from the "rount-trippable" classes then there's not too much repetition in the code - and it's *guidance* to put one type per file but not required. I'd be perfectly happy seeing a `Cake.cs` file that contained a `Cake` class that contains most of the properties and a `CakeSerializable : Cake` class with the `x` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, what I did to make this "force" work(a bit hackish):

I created custom `JsonConverter` that use custom `IContractResolver` that ignores `[JsonIgnore]` only for writing in `WriteJson`.

```
public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    ...

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // somehow using serializer passed to this method doesn't seem to work
        var token = JToken.FromObject(value, new JsonSerializer()
        {
            ContractResolver = new DontIgnoreContractResolver()
        });
        token.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}

public class DontIgnoreContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var jsonProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (jsonProperty.Ignored)
        {
            jsonProperty.Ignored = false;
        }
        return jsonProperty;
    }
}
```

but for `ReadJson` it uses default contract resolver and ignores the property. But yeah, that's possible.